# Create image files which don't appear in galley

Tags: java, android, bitmap, kotlin

I'm creating some image files from bitmaps in my android app and I don't like them to be shown in device gallery. Just like Telegram that saves images in Telegram folder but they never show up in gallery. How can I reach that?

Comment: Save in GetFilesDir(). Or in a directory in which you create an empty file with name `.nomedia`.

Comment: @greenapps That's right thanks. You could've written an answer.